# Scrolling a Page after Validation showing Validation Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a button on the bottom of the page OnClick it validates the form fields and if there is no valid field it displays a pop up message to enter the required fields using asp.net Validation Summary Control.
I want that when it showing the pop up once user click on OK buttom of pop up window then it should scroll to top of the page to form area.
Does any one have idea how to handle this to jump the page up?
I am working in asp.net 3.5 +VS 2010.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a form element or the form and `scrollTo()` it:

```
 function scrollToElement(id)
 {
      var formElement = document.getElementById(id);
      if(formElement){
          window.scrollTo(0, formElement.offsetTop);
      }
 }
```

[JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/uqapis/3)

Comment: how i would catch the OK click event on pop up summary window?